# Is a blank try and catch IndexOutOfBoundsException valid at the end of a while loop of if statements in C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, try-catch, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm finishing an unfinished C# WinForms project, which is a save game editor for an unspecified game. I noticed that character portraits and icons' IDs have a valid range of 1 to 905, but there was no code to verify that the character ID is within that range, so I opted to fix it. I have an in-progress solution to this, with the code for it (with a lot of function names partially redacted) at the end of this post, and wanted to know if it would work. Visual Studio says there are no formatting errors, but I know that alone will not quite be enough. I cannot compile to test because I am not quite at a stage where the code is compilable, with a lot of missing WinForms data. If the specific exception that I placed would not be appropriate, what exception would best fit? If a while loop should not be used in this way, what method should I use that doesn't require rewriting the entire code block from scratch? Here is the relevant code I have so far:

```cs
void getImage(int slot)
{
    short ID = 0;

    if (slot == 1)
    {
        try
        {
            ID = convertStringtoID(comboBoxSlot1ID.Text);
        }
        catch (System.FormatException)
        {
            ID = 0;
        }

        while (ID > 0 && ID < 906)
        {
            if (ID < 10)
            {
                pictureBoxSlot1Portrait.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("00" + ID);
                pictureBoxSlot1Icon.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("icon00" + ID);
            }
            else if (ID > 9 && ID < 100)
            {
                pictureBoxSlot1Portrait.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("0" + ID);
                pictureBoxSlot1Icon.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("icon0" + ID);
            }
            else if (ID > 99 && ID < 906)
            {
                pictureBoxSlot1Portrait.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("" + ID);
                pictureBoxSlot1Icon.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("icon" + ID);
            }
            else
            {
                try { }
                catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    ID = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have not yet been able to try or test anything yet; this is merely a question regarding the valid use of C# code. I also saw just 1 question that was similar, but not the same, as my question in the 'possibly related questions' section before posting this, although it did partially indicate that what I am doing may be okay. I am expecting the code to throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if `ID` is greater than 905, and read the proper image file if not.

Edit: Okay, I have revised the code significantly, using feedback posted here. I have ended up with the following code, which shows no errors in Visual Studio, and despite others saying 'it is improper to use exceptions to control flow', works for my use case. Also, I am technically not using them to control anything, just that I want an exception window to pop up for anyone who has a save file with a character ID greater than 905, so that they know that their save file is likely corrupted. I want the program to still be able to continue operation afterward, and not have this error be fatal. Here is the revised code:

```cs
void getImage(int slot)
{
    short ID = 0;
    if (slot == 1)
    {
        try
        {
            ID = convertStringtoID(comboBoxSlot1ID.Text);
        }

        catch (System.FormatException)
        {
            ID = 0;
        }

        if (ID < 10)
        {
            pictureBoxSlot1Portrait.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("00" + ID);
            pictureBoxSlot1Icon.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("icon00" + ID);
        }

        else if (ID > 9 && ID < 100)
        {
            pictureBoxSlot1Portrait.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("0" + ID);
            pictureBoxSlot1Icon.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("icon0" + ID);
        }

        else if (ID > 99 && ID < 906)
        {
            pictureBoxSlot1Portrait.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("" + ID);
            pictureBoxSlot1Icon.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("icon" + ID);
        }

        else if (ID > 905)
        {
            throw(System.InvalidOperationException);
            ID = 0;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I am expecting the code to throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if `ID` is greater than 905, and read the proper image file if not."* - Then you'll need to wrap the reading inside the `try`. The `try...catch` will only catch exceptions that occur within the `try` block. As yours is currently empty it does nothing. (I'm also not _entirely_ certain if `IndexOutOfRangeException` is the type of exception you'll get, when you get the chance to try it, you'll find out).

Comment: You're relying too much on exceptions that can be avoided by testing the conditions first. Replace the try/catch that does `convertStringtoID` with `int.TryParse` (and no try/catch), and test the bounds of any array you're accessing to prevent `IndexOutOfRangeException` from happening at all.

Comment: Something worth noting for your ongoing development... *"I cannot compile to test because I am not quite at a stage where the code is compilable, with a lot of missing WinForms data."* - You don't need the entire application up and running to test a single conceptual theory/question.  You can easily create and test a separate program which sets up and validates exactly and only the thing you want to test.

Comment: Reduce nesting by converting the slot check at the top to a guard clause: `if (slot != 1) return;` Since `convertStringtoID()` is a custom method, I'd also change it to make sure it doesn't throw and just returns `0` directly.

Comment: @Nickistired Alright, that makes sense. Would a `throw` with an exception, followed by `ID = 0`, then `continue` be better? If so, which exception would be best to throw? I will edit my post with an updated question.

Comment: @Maq That can work, but it's poor practice (and crazy-slow from a performance perspective) to use exception handling for logical program flow.

Comment: @madreflection I will take your suggestion regarding  `int.TryParse(convertStringtoID)` and implement it, as it would likely make the code faster, provided that I find a way to make `ID = 0` if it fails. I definitely want this behavior, as the file `000.png` exists and is a blank image with an X mark drawn on it, to indicate 'unknown character', or 'no character', and is set to be the default image up of the program before opening the game save file as well.

Comment: `ID = int.TryParse(comboBoxSlot1ID.Text), out int temp) ? temp : 0;`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I don't care about performance loss, as there is a lot of overhead loading the form data as a whole already. A few more milliseconds lost per tab refresh operation will not hurt the user in any way here. It's pretty standard for save editors to take a second or 2 to apply values in memory when dealing with lots of different fields, literally all other save editors have this problem.

Comment: @madreflection I've never used TryParse before, and didn't know the arguments that it supports. This will help immensely. Thanks. Anyway, I think you missed a second `(` after `int.TryParse` in your example; there's 2 `)`, but only 1 `(`.

Comment: You're right, unbalanced. Going too fast.  But rather, the first `)` shouldn't be there. Anyway, I just realized that `ID` is a `short`, so you need to use `short.TryParse` instead.

Comment: `ID = short.TryParse(comboBoxSlot1ID.Text, out short temp) ? temp : 0;`

Comment: @Map performance is the least of the reasons to avoid it.

Comment: Also, @JoelCoehoorn, I cannot do `if slot != 1`, because `slot` has a valid range of 1 to 3, and `slot` is manually passed in 3 locations in the code. After the section of code I listed is the exact same code posted twice more, only used for slots 2 and 3 instead.

Comment: @Maq The code in the question only works for slot `1`. Anything else just quits the method. But given the elided code, you should do something similar to how I changed the `ID + 000`, so the same set of code can use the variable appropriately to work for all three options

Comment: Oh, wait, @madreflection that won't work, as the function `convertStringtoID` is a custom function that uses the name of the character to fetch the ID of the character, not simply a function that converts the string interpretation of the character ID to a short. I tested it, and Visual Studio says 'not all code paths return a value', so I made sure the code made sense; it doesn't.

Comment: The character information should be inputs to the function, not pulled from out of the air. What you have here is an impure function and it *will* eventually be the source of bugs.

Comment: Oh, never mind again, I was looking at another function, and the error was because I placed a `}` at the wrong location. Turns out that the string interpretation on `ID` is indeed being converted to a `short` in the code above. I will make sure to include that in the update to the OP.

Comment: @madreflection Okay, I tried the code you suggested, and it is now saying `cannot implicitly convert 'int' to 'short', which is basically saying that `comboBoxSlot1ID.Text` is being interpreted as an int rather than a string... This is all kinds of weird. I did the following:

`short ID = 0    
ID = short.TryParse(comboBoxSlot1ID.Text);
` 
It's telling me that I should do:

`short ID = 0    
ID = (short)(short.TryParse(comboBoxSlot1ID.Text));`

Which seems very odd.

Comment: `short.TryParse` returns a boolean value indicating whether parsing succeeded. Casting that to `short` makes no sense. You're missing the `? temp : 0` part. Based on the boolean return, that uses `temp` (from `out short temp`) if it succeeded, or `0` if it failed; one of those two gets assigned to `ID`.

Comment: `comboBoxSlot1ID.Text` is a string. There's no way it's being interpreted as an int without you explicitly doing so; maybe it's because you're using `int.TryParse` (because that's what I said in the first place) and the result of that expression *is* an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ID = convertStringtoID(comboBoxSlot1ID.Text);
```

This is a custom method. Rather than wrap it in a try/catch, make it return the default `0` value. While I'm here, that comboBox should also be given as an argument to the `getImage()` method (and the potriat/icon pair returned as a result, maybe in a tuple).

I understand you might not have that option, and assuming you have a legitimate need to use it instead of a simple `int.Parse()` or `int.TryParse()`, or if it's used in other places and expected to throw. In that case, I then look at the `catch` value and see this:

```
ID = 0
```

... and then notice this:

```
while (ID > 0 && ID < 906)
```

Put them together, and we can just exit the method right away.

```
try
{
    ID = convertStringtoID(comboBoxSlot1ID.Text);
}
catch ()
{
     return;
}
```

Looking more at this loop:

```
while (ID > 0 && ID < 906)
```

Nothing inside that loop ever changes `ID`, so the loop would run **forever**. You want `if()` instead of `while()`.

I also see the conditional expressions used to decide how many `0`s you need to prefix the ID value. You can replace all that like this:

```
pictureBoxSlot1Portrait.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject($"{ID:000}");
pictureBoxSlot1Icon.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject($"dot{ID:000}");
```

Another item, for the question about the empty try:

```
 else
 {
     try { }
     catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException)
     {
         ID = 0;
     }
}
```

The `try` has nothing in it, least of all anything that would ever throw an exception, and therefore the `catch` will **NEVER** run. It seems like you just want this:

```
else
{
    ID = 0;
}
```

And I need to caution here about using exceptions for program logic control flow in the first place. It's *extremely poor practice*. Rather, exceptions should reserved for events that are genuinely exceptional or unexpected.

But really, I'd skip that `else()` completely, since we **already know logically from the checks made when entering the block that the value is in the expected range.**

Finally, I saw this comment:

> slot has a valid range of 1 to 3 ... after the section of code I listed is the exact same code posted twice more, only used for slots 2 and 3 instead.

We can improve on that like this:

```
if (--slot < 0 || slot > 2) return;
var portraits = new PictureBox[] {pictureBoxSlot1Portrait, pictureBoxSlot2Portrait, pictureBoxSlot3Portrait};
var icons = new PicutureBox[] {pictureBoxSlot1Icon, pictureBoxSlot2Icon, pictureBoxSlot3Icon};
var combos = new ComboBox[] {comboBoxSlot1ID, comboBoxSlot2ID, comboBoxSlot3ID};
```

And then use the new array variables when needed:

```
ID = convertStringtoID(combos[slot].Text);
// ...
portraits[slot].Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject($"{ID:000}");
icons[slot].Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject($"dot{ID:000}");
```

*Even better if the arrays are defined for this at the class level*, to avoid fresh allocations each time this runs, but I'll leave that change for another time.

Put it all together, and the method reduces to this:

```
void getImage(int slot)
{
   if (--slot < 0 || slot > 2) return; //also adjusts from 1-based slot to 0-based array index

   var portraits = new PictureBox[] {pictureBoxSlot1Portrait, pictureBoxSlot2Portrait, pictureBoxSlot3Portrait};
   var icons = new PicutureBox[] {pictureBoxSlot1Icon, pictureBoxSlot2Icon, pictureBoxSlot3Icon};
   var combos = new ComboBox[] {comboBoxSlot1ID, comboBoxSlot2ID, comboBoxSlot3ID};

   short ID = 0;
   try {
      ID = convertStringtoID(combos[slot].Text);
   } catch() { return; }

   if (ID <= 0 || ID >= 906) return;

   portraits[slot].Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject($"{ID:000}");
   icons[slot].Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject($"dot{ID:000}");     
}
```

This now works with only about 1/6 the code of the original and saves three levels of indentation. That it will also be faster is just a bonus.

There are further improvements that can be made as well, to better decouple the UI from the back end and simplify the code, but this is enough for today. But it's worth repeating here that the only exception ever thrown or even tested is for the `convertStringtoID()` method, which could likely be rewritten to avoid the need. No other try/catch is needed.

Comment: Or just `if (!short.TryParse(comboBoxSlot1ID.Text), out short ID) || ID is not (> 0 and <= 906)) return;`

Comment: @madreflection Probably, but I'm will to grant the benefit of the doubt that parsing an ID may be doing an additional check vs just parsing a short. Probably not, but stranger things have happened. When it comes to it, I'd also like to see the combBox given as an argument to the method.

Comment: @Maq I hope you've seen the final revision of the last snippet here.

Comment: Oooh, now that is extremely concise. The original developer of the save editor did say it is very unoptimized, so shortening the code that much while also minimizing the changes needed elsewhere is very nice indeed. I only see 1 issue, as you pointed out in the comments above, parsing the ID is indeed doing other checks, 2 in fact, 1 check on ID (specifically, if it is -1, that means the slot is null, as in not unlocked) and 1 check that depends on another value elsewhere in the code. The 'not unlocked' case only happens for the first chapter of the game, but is still valid to check.

Comment: Yep, code covers all edge cases, and needed only 3 changes elsewhere to work. I have implemented the code within this answer, and get zero errors. I'm marking this as the best answer. I really need to learn how to write shorthand code, though, as I feel it would save file size in my code. I never knew you could put WinForms object names into arrays and pull them from the array. That's new knowledge gained; if I knew that sooner, I would've been able to simplify this code on my own. Still, I usually code in Ruby Game Scripting System, and merely am a helper with other code. C# is new to me.

Comment: @Maq for the Winforms names, you do have to be a little careful, since the objects aren't created until the InitializeComponent() method runs in the constructor. If you try to initialize them as class-level fields, the variables are there, but the objects are not yet (the variables are still `null`)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn so by initialized as class-level, you mean just under the main class of the Designer file? If so, then that is indeed the case for me. It literally does InitializeComponent() shortly after `partial class MainMenu`, then follows with the rest of the code. Does WinForms data get loaded before the main code normally, or after? Depending on that, I may have to rewrite my code. Also, is it safe to set max values for numericUpDown fields based on conditions in the main code? Like, `if (codeValue == "foo") { this.numericUpDown_bar.Maximum = new decimal(new int[] {999999,0,0,0}) }`?

Comment: @Maq Winforms data is loaded in the `InitializeComponent()` method. But fields are initialized _before_ the `InitializeComponent()` method. So if you build the array as a field that is initialized as part of the field definition, the control objects don't exist yet.

Comment: Okay, 2 more questions, the first is likely a typo on your part, but I wanted to be sure. First, in `if (--slot < 0 || slot > 2)`, did you mean `if (--slot < 0 || --slot > 2)` instead? You put the `--` in front of one and not the other. Second, if the code was working well already, would formatting the code this way change anything? I can interpret code and adapt it at the basic level, but writing my own code, let alone understanding the internal workings of it, is still beyond me currently, although I am willing to learn if need be.

Comment: Oh, I just now realized that the part about initialization order was in reply to my question regarding initialization order. So your answer answers my question sufficiently, and reaffirms that my code should work after all, as the code I am referencing in the Designer file is in the MainMenu.cs file, and does contain fields that are filled upon loading a save file with data from said save file; in other words, they are not null. Until the save file is loaded, all fields are locked by default, so it should be safe.

Comment: Welp, Visual Studio complained about my edit, so it didn't work. Either way, it's fine. I didn't HAVE to have that edit anyway.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn , can you please answer my first question? That is all the information I need to finish up my code. Also, is there a DM system on SOF

Comment: @Maq The `--` only goes before the first `slot` in the conditional expression. It will _change the value of the method's `slot` variable when it runs_, so for the second part it's already been applied, and later code wants a 0-based array index instead of a 1-based position.

Answer (score 2):

Take note of this structure:

```
try
{
    ID = convertStringtoID(comboBoxSlot1ID.Text);
}
catch (System.FormatException)
{
    ID = 0;
}
```

Notice how the `try` block wraps an operation which could potentially fail.  Contrast that with this structure:

```
try
{
}
catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException)
{
    ID = 0;
}
```

What operation *within that `try` block* might fail and why?

Whatever operation might fail would go within the `try` block.  If that operation is an entire loop then that entire loop would go there.

---

***However***, what you have here isn't really a valid use of exceptions in the first place.  Don't rely on exceptions for conditions you can directly check in the code.

It's worth noting the loop logic:

```
while (ID > 0 && ID < 906)
```

If `ID` is not within this range then the loop won't iterate again anyway.  Outside the context of this, if you ever want to set `ID` to `0` when it's not within this range, that's a simple `if` condition:

```
if (ID <= 0 || ID >= 906)
{
    ID = 0;
}
```

Or, perhaps within the scope of your specific code, if the goal of that `else` block is to set `ID` to `0` then you can just... set `ID` to `0`:

```
else
{
    ID = 0;
}
```

(Note that even the structurally valid try/catch shown earlier can also be replaced with logic.  Take a look at [the `TryParse` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse).)

Comment: I have edited my question. As stated in my newest edit, I want the user of my application to know that their save file may be corrupt, as a character ID value of higher than 905 indicates a corrupt file; there are other checks in place before this code to validate that the save file is the correct size as well as other checks to validate data types. It just is that the original developer of this save editor abandoned the code (I have their blessing) and had left out this particular check. I want to throw an exception specifically (as I just said) to notify the user of erroneous files.

Comment: @Maq: And in the revised code, what problem do you encounter?  You've updated the question, but what is the updated *question*?

Comment: The question is still the same, whether it is valid, even if not recommended. Anyway, the answer by @JoelCoehoorn is the best response, in my opinion, as it fits all edge cases while also needing minimal changes elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

```
try { }
catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException)
{
      ID = 0;
}
```

This does nothing and should be removed.

```
"00" + ID
```

you can just do `ID.ToString("000")` to get a zero-prefixed three digit string for the number.

```
I am expecting the code to throw IndexOutOfBoundsException if ID is greater than 905
```

From the [ResourceManager.GetObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getobject?view=net-8.0)

> Returns Object
>
> The value of the resource localized for the caller's current culture settings. If an appropriate resource set exists but name cannot be found, the method returns null.

So why are you expecting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

```
while (ID > 0 && ID < 906)
```

you are not incrementing the ID inside the loop, so this loop will be infinite.

```
I noticed that character portraits and icons IDs have a valid range of 1 to 905
```

It is rarely a good idea to hardcode such values, since things like this is often subject to change. You should probably list all the icons in the resource file and present the valid options from some kind of list. Or to just try retrieving whatever the user enters, and inform the user about the failure if it does not exist.

Comment: This answer is technically flawed, as I am not working on a game. I am working on a save game editor, which does not directly have to do with game code in any form. I already stated that I am working on a save game editor in the original question.

Comment: Also, regarding the prefixing, the code is trying to load a numbered image that is zero-prefixed, and that string is actually a filename, so I do not know how that would apply here.